# Can additional charge be put on plasma?

Tags: charge, plasma-physics

We all know that plasma is electrically conductive. My question is that is it possible to somehow place more charge on it (lets say like a capacitor) such that it produces its own electric field around itself?

Comment: Sure, but for most plasmas it won't change anything significant about the charge densities. The few additional charges won't make much difference.

Comment: Are you asking about Debye shielding?  In a space plasma, there are no mechanical forces to hold two sheets of charge apart so the capacitor idea would not work.  In a lab plasma, of course you can use a battery to do work on the system and impose an external field on the plasma.  However, as CuriousOne said, not much would change...